# Repeat div every click angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a counter in angularjs

```
$scope.count = 0;
    $scope.increment = function(){
        $scope.count = $scope.count + 1;
        console.log("count " + $scope.count);
    };
    $scope.decrement = function() {
        if($scope.count > 0) {
            $scope.count = $scope.count - 1;
        }
    };
```

and i would display a div if the count value is more than 1. The counter is incremented by a click in a button. Every time i click i increment the counter. Actually the counter goes well but i would create a div in each click. Now i'm be able to generate only one div. This is html part

```
<a class="uk-button" data-ng-click="increment()">
    <i class="uk-icon-plus" ></i>
    New div
</a>
<div class="uk-panel" data-ng-if="count >= 1">
    <hr>
    <div class="uk-panel uk-width-1-1 qt-add-row">
        <form class="uk-form uk-form-horizontal uk-float-left">
            <div class="uk-form-row"  data-ng-repeat="item in data.row">
                <label class="uk-form-label" for="form">{{item.name}}</label>
                <div class="uk-form-controls uk-width-1-1">
                    <input id="form" class="uk-width-1-1" type="text" placeholder="{{item.name}}" ng-model="field.value">
                        <span style="position: absolute" class="uk-button-group">

                            <a class="uk-button" href="#">
                                <i class="uk-icon-close"></i>
                            </a>
                        </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which `div` do you want to repeat? The parent-most `.uk-panel` below `a`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `ng-repeat` directive to your `div`. Unfortunately `ng-repeat` accepts only objects and arrays, not numbers. So you'll have to also modify your increment/decrement functions a bit

```
<div class="uk-panel" data-ng-if="countArr.length > 0" data-ng-repeat="i in countArr">

$scope.countArr = [];
$scope.increment = function() {
    $scope.countArr.push('');
};
$scope.decrement = function() {
    $scope.countArr.splice(0, 1);
};
```

Comment: mmh, unfortunatelly in this way the div not appears on click not once.

Comment: Right, I forgot that `ng-repeat` accepts objects and arrays, not numbers. Take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: sorry matewka if i rewrite but i got a problem. The repeat of the div works well but i have a form with an input text inside it. So if i repeat this div incremented it 3 times, i will have 3 times the same form with same text writing. I need repeat this form but they would be differents between them. Understand?